# How to store multiple row base on the ID in SQL into variable in php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I have 3 tables in phpmyadmin. disease_table, medicine_table, disease_medicine_table.

Case: The disease can have multiple medicines that's why I made the third table named disease_medicine table that linked the disease table and medicine table.

My problem is how to get all the records of the disease.

I'm using codeigniter framework

My desired result is:

- id - disease_name - medicines
- 1 - toothache - med1,med2,med3,med4
- 2 - headache - med4,med8,med2,med5

Or do you have a better idea to fix my problem?

This is my disease table

- id(int11)
- disease_name(varchar255)

This my medicine table

- id(int11)
- med_name(varchar255)
- dosage_strength(varchar255)
- price(decimal65,2)

This my disease_medicine table

- id(int11)
- disease_id(int11)
- medicine_id(int11)
- dosage(varchar255)
- quantity(int64)

Im going to display the data in DataTable server side and this is my code
Ajax controller

```
public function get_diseases_for_table() {
$data = [];

if(($ajax_data = $this->input->get()) && $this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
    extract($ajax_data);
    $data = [
        'draw' => $draw,
        'recordsTotal' => $this->diseases->get_diseases_records_total(),
        'recordsFiltered' => $this->diseases->get_diseases_records_filtered($ajax_data)
    ];

    $data['data'] = $this->diseases->get_diseases($ajax_data);
}
$this->view = FALSE;
echo json_encode($data);
```

}

Model

```
public function get_diseases_records_total() {
    $sql = 'SELECT d.id, d.disease_name, m.med_name, d.created_at ';
    $sql .= 'FROM diseases d ';
    $sql .= 'INNER JOIN diseases_medicines dm ON d.id = dm.disease_id ';
    $sql .= 'INNER JOIN medicines m ON dm.medicine_id = m.id ';

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query->num_rows();
}

public function get_diseases_records_filtered($data) {
    extract($data);
    $params = [];

    $sql = 'SELECT d.id, d.disease_name, m.med_name, d.created_at ';
    $sql .= 'FROM diseases d ';
    $sql .= 'INNER JOIN diseases_medicines dm ON d.id = dm.disease_id ';
    $sql .= 'INNER JOIN medicines m ON dm.medicine_id = m.id ';
    $sql .= 'WHERE 1 ';

    if(!empty($search['value'])){
        $sql .= 'AND (d.id = ? ';
        $sql .= 'OR d.disease_name LIKE ? ';
        $sql .= 'OR m.med_name LIKE ? ';
        $sql .= 'OR d.created_at LIKE ?) ';
    }

    if(!empty($search['value'])){
        $params[] = $search['value'];
        $params[] = $search['value'];
        $params[] = $search['value'];
        $params[] = $search['value'];
    }

    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $params);

    return $query->num_rows();
}

public function get_diseases($data, $details = false) {
    extract($data);
    $params = [];

    $sql = 'SELECT d.id, d.disease_name, m.med_name, d.created_at ';
    $sql .= 'FROM diseases d ';
    $sql .= 'INNER JOIN diseases_medicines dm ON d.id = dm.disease_id ';
    $sql .= 'INNER JOIN medicines m ON dm.medicine_id = m.id ';
    $sql .= 'WHERE 1 ';

    if(!empty($search['value'])){
        $sql .= 'AND (d.id = ? ';
        $sql .= 'OR d.disease_name LIKE ? ';
        $sql .= 'OR m.med_name LIKE ? ';
        $sql .= 'OR d.created_at LIKE ?) ';
    }

    if(isset($order)){
        $sql .= 'ORDER BY ' . $columns[$order[0]['column']]['data'] . ' ' . strtoupper($order[0]['dir']) . ' ';//$order[0]['column']
    }
    $sql .= 'LIMIT ?, ?';

    if(!empty($search['value'])){
        $params[] = $search['value'];
        $params[] = '%' . $search['value'] . '%';
        $params[] = '%' . $search['value'] . '%';
        $params[] = '%' . $search['value'] . '%';
    }

    $params[] = (int)$start;
    $params[] = (int)$length;


    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $params);

    return ( $query->num_rows() ) ? $query->result() : FALSE;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using mysql <> sql-server.

Comment: What sort of medicine are you storing that have a price which needs a `decimal(65, 2)`?

Comment: Im using mysql @SeanLange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this query:

```
SELECT d.id, d.disease_name, m.med_name
FROM disease d
JOIN disease_medicine dm ON d.id=dm.disease_id
JOIN medicine m on m.id=dm.medicine_id
```

The result will be:

```
1    disA    med1
1    disA    med2
2    disB    med3
2    disB    med4
...
```

You can then work through the results to compile things as you wish.  For instance if you put all results in `$rows`

```
$results = [];
foreach($rows as $row){
    if(!isset($results[$row['disease_name']]) $results[$row['disease_name']]='';
    $results[$row['disease_name']] .= ',' $row['med_name'];
}
```

Your `$results` will then look like:

```
[
    'disA'=>'med1,med2,',
    'disB'=>'med3,med4,',
    ...
]
```

If you care, you can use `rtrim()` to remove the trailing commas.

Comment: I get this error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: That has to do with how you fetch data from your query results.  Look into the different fetch options. There are typically 3: 1) fetch as an associative array (that's what my answer assumes), 2) fetch as an indexed array, and 3) fetch as an object. If you're dealing with objects, you can adjust the code easily, for instance replace `$row['med_name']` with `$row->med_name`

Comment: Im going to display it in the datatable server side code and returning the result of array as what you suggested and I get this error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: look at my last comment (above your comment)

Comment: can you check my code? please I edited my question I included my code up there

Comment: @MichaelAmaleona I deleted the last comment. Welcome to StackOverflow and happy coding Michael.

Comment: @BetleJuice Thank you for your advice and sorry for asking too much. I will open a new question and this time i will be more specific and your answer is gonna help me in my other query thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try :

$diseasesWithMedicines =  $this->getAllmedicinesFromDisease();

```
public function getAllmedicinesFromDisease()
{   
    // first get all disease
    $diseases = $this->getAllDisease();

    // for each disease get all medicine 
    foreach ($diseases as $key => $disease) {
        $diseases[$key]['medicines'] = $this->getAllmedicinesByDiseaseId($disease['id']);
    }

    return $diseases;
}

public function getAllDisease()
{
    $this->db->select("disease_medicine.id ,disease_table.disease_name");
    $this->db->from("disease_table");
    $this->db->group_by("disease_table.disease_name");
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ( $query->num_rows() == 0 ) {
        throw new exception("Erro");
    }

    return $query->result_array();
}

public function getAllmedicinesByDiseaseId($diseaseId) 
{
    if (empty($diseaseId)) {
       throw new exception("Erro");
    } 

    $this->db->select("medicine_table.med_name");
    $this->db->from("disease_medicine_table");
    $this->db->join("disease_table","disease_table.id = disease_medicine_table.disease_id");
    $this->db->join("medicine_table","medicine_table.id = .disease_medicine_table.medicine_id");
    $this->db->where("disease_table.id", $diseaseId);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ( $query->num_rows() == 0 ) {
        throw new exception("Erro");
    }

    return $query->result_array();
}
```